# google-visualization-error-0, C is null

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, google-visualization

We are using angular-google-chart module and
We have two google LineChart' graphs and on toggle one of them gets shown by setting ng-show=flag
If both of them are set to ng-show=true then I can see both are drawn properly. but if I control ng-show with flag then I get following error.

`Chart not displayed due to error: c is null. Full error object follows.
ng-goog...hart.js (line 196)
Object { id="google-visualization-errors-0",  message="c is null",  options={...},  more...}`

Let me what all info you need.

Error shown in UI -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error – my Google Material Bar Chart did not display after being rendered the second time (updated).

```
<div ng-show="searched">
<div flex google-chart chart="avgChart"></div>
```

I had to set my "avgChart" variable to "null" before I drew the chart again (or before this code was 'executed' again). So right after I leave the page with the google-chart directive, I run this in my controller:

```
$scope.avgChart = null;
```

Now my chart draws everytime without the mysterious "*Chart not displayed due to error: . Full error object follows."*

More info here: https://github.com/angular-google-chart/angular-google-chart/issues/185